# If the sum of two even integers is an even integer, what conclusion can you make about the difference of two odd numbers?

Tags: logic, proof-verification

"You can't make any conclusion from the 'if' statement, about the difference of two odd integers." That's what I said.

I tried to see if we could, from the equation "2m + 2n = 2(m + n)", have any equation of "m - n" (m and n being two odd integers here), but all I got was the truism "m + n = m + n".

[No description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QoDkI.png)

[Solving the prompt with the new information given by fellow stack users](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0sdx5.jpg)

**(Another correction: The result is 2(m - n); made a bad calculation there)**

Comment: Looking at the image, I don't think it's asking you to make a conclusion from just the previous conclusion. You should be able to use other properties/facts as well. But I'm not so sure

Comment: I think it is a totally separate exercise, which follows the same patern as the one about the sum of even ntegers: write down some examples and then proof your 'conjecture': find the general form of a odd integer and then look at their difference. There is definitely an (interesting) conclusion to make :)

Comment: It's an awkwardly phrased question. "What conclusion..." has a meaning in regular language, and a more precise meaning in mathematics. If this is the *only* thing you know about even numbers, and that "odd" numbers are simply numbers that are not even numbers, then you are correct, there is nothing to be concluded.

Comment: But in the image, it's not clear you are being asked for a conclusion from the first result, but rather, what conclusion can you make via a similar process that let you conclude the first result.

Comment: If we want to be really picky, maybe: If $m$ and $n$ are odd, they are of the form $m = 2x + 1$ and $n = 2y + 1$. Let $a = 2x$ and $b = -2y$. Both $a$ and $b$ are even. By commutativity, distributivity and associativity, we have: $m - n = (2x + 1) - (2y + 1) = (2x - 2y) +1 - 1 = a + b$ which is an even number. This is all, of course, unnecessary.

Comment: Ok (to everyone). I'm working it; I'll post the picture for "critique".

Comment: @Student Added a new picture.

Comment: @swift: correct result, but you have a computational error: the term $-2$ should not be there.

Comment: @Student Corrected it. Another thing I'm working on, being thorough with "basic" computing that can render your whole operation false.

Comment: The question being asked is ambiguous IMO.  Give that a sum of even numbers is even; Odd is different  than even; and *nothing* else about the definitions of even or odd we can't conclude anything.  Even if we added that we knew all numbers are odd or even but never both.  We couldn't conclude anything.  But if we actually know the meaning of even and odds, we can very easily reach a conclusion that the difference is even.  Although it has nothing to do with the sum of evens being even.

Comment: Okay looking at the image, they are definitely *NOT* asking you what you can conclude from the sums of evens.   That are asking you to subtract some odds, notice a pattern, make a conjecture, and justify with deductive reasoning why the conjecture must be true.

Answer (score 2):

Each odd integer $m$ can be represented by $m=2 m'+1$ (or equivanent $m'=\frac{m-1}2$).

Thus the difference of two odd integers is
$m-n=(2 m'+1)-(2n'+1)=2(m'-n')$. This is even for any numbers $m, n$.

Comment: Thank you. A quick question, if you don't mind: why did you choose to go with 2m' + 1 and 2n' + 1 to designate odd integers, as opposed to simply setting up the syllogism with m, and n...and saying: "given any two odd integers m and n, the difference m - n = 2k, k being the number obtained by dividing the result of m - n by 2" Then concluding that, given we can write m - n as the product of two and another number, that means the difference of any two odd integers m and n is an even number; couldn't we proceed as such?

Comment: @Swift : in this exercise I would not do it, since the main part is about showing that the 'odd parts' cancel out (and what you claim to be a proof is basically what you have to prove.)

Comment: You're right. But, since I knew the method only because I was inspiring myself from how they solved the "even integers problem", I was wondering if there was any reason to choose this specific set-up. @Student

Answer (score 1):

We can employ the proposition that a sum of evens is even as follows:

$\qquad\ m,n$ odd $\,\Rightarrow\, m = j+1,\ n = k+1\,$ for even $\,j,k$

thus $\, m- n = j + (-k)$ is the sum of evens, so is even by the proposition.

---

More generally, $\bmod k\!:\,\  m\equiv a\equiv  n\,\Rightarrow\, m-n\equiv 0.\,$  Above is special case: $\,a=1,\, k= 2.$